# invert float using other float

Tags: floating-point, glsl

I have a very simple problem but I'm throwing my brain against the wall as I can't find a solution.

I'm using a shader processor in an embedded system and can't use conditionals due to bad performance in the fragment shader.

I have two floats, both can either be 0 or 1.

I want to invert the value of the first float if the second float is 1.

basically

```
if(floatA==1.0)
    {
        if(floatB==1.0)
        {
            floatB=0.0;
        }
        else
        {
            floatB=1.0;
        }
    }
```

-- just without conditions but mathematically x..X

any ideas? :D

Comment: You should not compare floats in this strict way since it is not guaranteed that they hold a certain value because of their lack of precision.

Comment: @djmj That's in general just plain wrong. They're not guaranteed to hold such values after any imprecise mathematical operation (which may be the case here, but who knows). But comparing floats with exact values (that are guaranteed to be representable, or even guaranteed to be the outcome of certain operations, as 0 definitely is) is in itself not generally a bad idea. I would rather consider dogmatic *don't compare floats*-approaches to lack understanding of the underlying floating point representation.

Comment: @ChristianRau was aware of this and as you said "yes who knows", with that code snippet no one knows what happens before thats why I said it. If i read a code snippet like this I assume everything before that code. If complete vertex- and fragment shader code would be shown my comment would maybe be different. Still voted up your detailed comment.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

`floatB = ( floatA * ( 1 - floatB )) + ((1 - floatA) * floatB )`

If floatA is 1, then `floatB = 1-floatB`, otherwise if floatA is zero, then `floatB = floatB`;

Comment: Was just about to edit my answer to this when I saw your solution!

Comment: +1 As a side note, when using a shading language like GLSL, you can even use a builtin function for the blend (`mix(floatB, 1.0-floatB, floatA)`), might even be faster than the handwritten one.